# 'NoneType' object is not callable in Jupyter

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I am trying to run simple commands in python using Jupyter, which takes some inputs from console and computes based on the value. However, a simple "input" command which used to work fine is not working now.

Command:

> num1 = input("Enter a number")

Exception:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-121-ff2dc32ed727> in <module>()
----> 1 num1 = input("Enter a number")

TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable
```

Comment: Somehow or other you have redefined `input`.  Instead of being the builtin function it is now `None`.

Comment: Yes, that had happened. I used "del" to delete the variable input and now everything works fine.